# Get average days open for issues per day (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, powerbi

I'm trying to create a chart in PowerBI that shows the average days open of issues in a database at each given time between two dates.

```
CREATE TABLE Issues
(IssueID int,IssueName varchar(10),created datetime, closed datetime);

INSERT INTO Issues
VALUES
(1,'a','2012-01-01 00:00:00', '2012-05-01 00:00:00'),
(2,'b','2012-03-01 00:00:00', '2012-06-01 00:00:00');
```

My first query shows all data in the database:

```
SELECT IssueID,
DATEDIFF(DAY,created,ISNULL(closed,GETDATE())) AS 'Days_Open'
FROM Issues
```

Results:

```
 IssueID    Days_Open
    1           4
    2           3
```

What I want to find is for each day, the issues open that day and average days open?

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME

SET @StartDate = '2012-01-01'
SET @EndDate = '2012-07-01'
```

Ex:
Issues open each day

```
Date         IssueID    Days_Open
2012-01-01      1           0
2012-02-01      1           1
2012-03-01      1           2
2012-03-01      2           0
2012-04-01      1           3
2012-04-01      2           1
2012-05-01      1           4
2012-05-01      2           2
2012-06-01      2           3
Day 07 has no issues
```

Average

```
Date         Average_Days_Open
2012-01-01      0 (1 issue just created)
2012-02-01      1 (1 issue - 1 day old)
2012-03-01      1 (2 issues - (2+0)/2 = 1)
2012-04-01      2 (2 issues - (3+1)/2 = 2)
2012-05-01      3 (2 issues - (4+2)/2 = 3)
2012-06-01      3 (1 issue - (0+3)/1 = 3)
2012-07-01      0 (Since there were no issues that day)
```

If i can get the data from both then I should be able to create a line chart in PowerBi similar to this:
[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFFzf.jpg)

Can someone please help out?

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?  You are asking for a fairly difficult query.

Comment: "`SELECT IssueID,
DATEDIFF(DAY,created,ISNULL(closed,GETDATE())) AS 'Days_Open'
FROM Issues`" -> `GETDATE()`is SQL server date function not a MySQL date function..

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, for beginner it could be fairly difficult . But once you get calendar table it is pretty straighfoward

Comment: @lad2025 Dude...I can't believe you actually answered it ;)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I would be faster, but SO went offline for about 5 min :)

Comment: Yeah...I was about to post something as well in another question...hate when that happens.  The SO devs don't spend enough time learning on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on syntax I guess it is SQL Server:

1) Query:

```
WITH CTE_DatesTable
AS
(
  SELECT CAST('20120101' as datetime) AS [date]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, [date])
  FROM CTE_DatesTable
  WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, [date]) <= '20120106'
)
SELECT [date] , i.IssueId,  DATEDIFF(DAY,i.created,d.[date]) AS Days_Open
FROM CTE_DatesTable d
JOIN Issues i
  ON d.date BETWEEN i.created AND i.closed
ORDER BY [date], IssueId
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0c47fcd0c4887fb1766f6a9bbda90e44)**

2) Query (average):

```
WITH CTE_DatesTable
AS
(
  SELECT CAST('20120101' as datetime) AS [date]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, [date])
  FROM CTE_DatesTable
  WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, [date]) <= '20120106'
)
SELECT [date] ,AVG( DATEDIFF(DAY,i.created,d.[date]))
FROM CTE_DatesTable d
JOIN Issues i
  ON d.date BETWEEN i.created AND i.closed
GROUP BY [date]
ORDER BY [date]
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7fbbdbb0a1609f6e08b29da54caa9fb4)**

The whole idea is to generate calendar table.

---

If you need dates that are out of range you could use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
WITH CTE_DatesTable
AS
(
  SELECT CAST('20120101' as datetime) AS [date]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, [date])
  FROM CTE_DatesTable
  WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, [date]) <= '20120107'
)
SELECT [date] , COALESCE(AVG( DATEDIFF(DAY,i.created,d.[date])),0)
FROM CTE_DatesTable d
LEFT JOIN Issues i
  ON d.date BETWEEN i.created AND i.closed
GROUP BY [date]
ORDER BY [date]
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo3](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3028bd02a327f5b3514ac79c6fb437db)**

Comment: One question: Can the data flow be inverted? Having the FROM Query search in the Issues table and RIGHT JOIN the CTE_DatesTable?